# Concerned about end of support for Python runtimes (python27 and python37)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

How can I update my app because it has developed on Python2.7 from last 5 years, and python 3 does not support some old programming concept?

> WARNING: Python 2.7 is no longer supported by the Python community as of 27 June, 2023. Python 2.7 will be end of support on 2024-01-30. As of 2024-01-30 you will no longer be able to deploy your App Engine Standard using python27. We recommend you to upgrade to the latest version of Python as soon as possible.

May I stop my application next 1 year to update it?

I have used wepapp2 and other library. I have to develop the whole project

It is not possible dear

Comment: 2023? Wasn't python 2.7 end-of-life already back in January 2020?

Comment: @James Z Yes, Officially python 2.7 end-of-life is in January 2020 as stated in the [Documentation](https://devguide.python.org/versions/#versions). But the mentioned date is the end of support for python. Already deployed apps are not directly affected in an immediate time frame. And the Google official [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/support-schedule#:~:text=Python%202.7,2026%2D01%2D31) shows it as `2024-01-31`.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i update my app because it has developed on Python2.7 from last 5 year, and python 3 does not sport some old programming concept?

Yes, you are correct. It may not support old programming concepts. But you can check with this [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/pyporting.html) which explains clearly about code changes required while migrating from python 2.7 to 3.x.

> May i stop my application next 1 year to update it?

No, it is not required to stop the application. You can check with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/migrate-to-second-gen/python-differences) for migrating 2.7 to 3.x. And also have a look at this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/lifecycle/runtime-lifecycle) for Runtime lifecycle.

**Note**: You must choose a more up-to-date runtime to deploy your application.